# Simple Tensorflow with Custom Packages on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, tensorflow

**The task**: Run a tensorflow train.py script I wrote in the cloud with at least 32GB of memory.

**Requirements**: The script has some dependencies like numpy, scipy, and mkt. I need to be able to install these. I just want a no-nonsense ssh shell like experience. I want to put all my files including the training data in a directory, pip install the packages if necessary, then just hit python train.py and let it run. I'm not looking to run a web app or have Google's machine learning platform do it for me.

All the tutorials around seem needlessly complicated, like they're meant for scaled deployments with http requests and all that. I'm looking for a simple way to run code on a server since my computer is too weak for machine learning.

Comment: Have you read this:  https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AppEngine -- use Compute Engine instead. Almost the same thing, but very simple and you are completely in control of what you run, what you install etc.

Simple steps that should work for you:
-Create a Compute Engine instance
-Chose operating system (Ubuntu xx, but you can choose others instead)
-Chose how many CPUs and how much memory you want (select Customize in order to set yourself the CPU/memory ratio rather than getting default options)
-Enable HTTP/HTTPs in order to be able to use Tensorboard later
-Once created, SSH into the machine. Python is already pre-installed (2.7 default, but 3.x also available as Python3 alias)
-Install Tensorflow, Numpy, Pandas, and whatever you want with simple PIP
-You can also install Bazel if you want to build Tensorflow from source and to speed up the CPU operations
-Install gcsfuse if you want to copy/paste stuff quickly from cloud storage buckets
-Use tmux if you want to run several Tensorflow sessions in parallel (i.e.to try different hyperparameters/etc.)

This is all very clean and simple and works really well. Don't forget to shut it down after finished. You can also create a Preemptable instance to make it super-cheap (but it can be shut down at any time without warning, but happens rarely).